# How do I align my div in the grid layout when I am using a media query for when the screen is less than 450 px?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to center my .logo div in the grid layout when using a media query for when the screen is less than 450 px. My .logo div contains an img inside of its, but does not center align. However, using justify-items: center; does not seem to work. How would I go about fixing this issue?

```
/* CSS */

@media screen and (max-width: 450px) {
/* Personal Projects*/

    .project {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-areas: 
        "logo"
        "desc";
        justify-items: center;
        width: 100%;
    }

    .project .logo {
        width: 100%;
        display: block;
        grid-area: logo;
        justify-items: center;
    }

    .project .logo img{
        width: 400px;
        height: auto;
    }


}
```

Comment: add your html too into a [snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)...

Comment: just add .project .logo {display: grid;} and its going to work fine.

Comment: Rather use  `margin-left: auto;` and `margin-right: auto` on image items. This has to do that justify-items needs special treatment in grid-layout  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/justify-items

Comment: Try adding `.project .logo img{text-align: center;margin: 0 auto}`